# Fonts/Org_01.h: No such file or directory

Tags: library

I have written one Arduino code for working with tft lcd 2.4 and  in it i used `<Fonts/Org_01.h>` new font ,It was working in my Win8 OS but now in Linux OS i have installed new Arduino in my Linux OS and in this Arduino i have get this error:

> exit status 1 Fonts/Org_01.h: No such file or directory

the entire codes are shown blown:

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Adafruit's core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h> // Adafruit's hardware-specific library
#include <TouchScreen.h>     //Touchscreen library
#include <Fonts/Org_01.h>    //Include a different font
#include <EEPROM.h>         //Include the EEPROM library to score the highscore
#include <MCUFRIEND_kbv.h>
MCUFRIEND_kbv tft;

#include <TimeLib.h>


bool backsensed = false;
bool resetsensed = false;


// most mcufriend shields use these pins and Portrait mode:
uint8_t YP = A1;  // must be an analog pin, use "An" notation!
uint8_t XM = A2;  // must be an analog pin, use "An" notation!
uint8_t YM = 7;   // can be a digital pin
uint8_t XP = 6;   // can be a digital pin


#define TS_MINX 100
#define TS_MINY 120
#define TS_MAXX 920
#define TS_MAXY 940
//Create the touchscreen object
TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);  //(data,data,data,data,sensitivity);

//Some of the tft pins
#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_CD A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0
// Optional, used to reset the display
#define LCD_RESET A4

#define REDBAR_MINX 80
#define GREENBAR_MINX 130
#define BLUEBAR_MINX 180
#define BAR_MINY 30
#define BAR_HEIGHT 250
#define BAR_WIDTH 30

//Create the tft object
//Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

// Define some TFT readable colour codes to human readable names
#define BLACK   0x0000
int BLUE = tft.color565(50, 50, 255);
#define DARKBLUE 0x0010
#define VIOLET 0x8888
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF
int GREY =  tft.color565(64, 64, 64);
#define GOLD 0xFEA0
#define BROWN 0xA145
#define SILVER 0xC618
#define LIME 0x07E0

int currentpcolour;


//Minimum and maximum pressure to sense the touch
#define MINPRESSURE 10
#define MAXPRESSURE 1000

#define DRAW_LOOP_INTERVAL 50  //The interval used instead of delay(); 

//Define the address used in the eeprom memory to store highscores
#define addr 0
int currentpage;

int currentWing;        //Used to flap the wings
int flX, flY, fallRate; //Used to calculete and store the bird's position
int pillarPos, gapPosition;  //Used tho draw the pillars
int score;              //Store the score
int highScore = 0;      //Store the highscore
bool running = false;   //Store weather flying or not
bool crashed = false;   //Store weather crashed or not
bool scrPress = false;  //Store weather sensed some touch and store
long nextDrawLoopRunTime;
int redval;
int greenval;
int blueval;

int redpos = BAR_MINY + 12;
int greenpos = BAR_MINY + 12;
int bluepos = BAR_MINY + 12;

int oldrpos = redpos;
int oldgpos = greenpos;
int oldbpos = bluepos;
int x, y;


int lastDay = 0;
int lastMonth = 0;
int lastYear = 0;
int lastHour = 0;
int lastMinute = 0;
int lastSecond=0;
int movementTimer = 0;
int menuOptions = 4;
int menuOption = 0;
int alarmHours = 0;
//int Heater_alarmMinutes = 0;
//int Heater_alarmSecond=10;
//int Motor_alarmSecond=10;
//int Motor_alarmMinutes=0;

byte Heater_alarmMinutes_end ;
byte Heater_alarmSecond_end;
byte Motor_alarmSecond_end;
byte Motor_alarmMinutes_end;


bool heater_key = 0;
bool backLightOn = 1;
int fadeValue = 255;

byte address=0;
byte value;

bool state=1;


//#$############# MLX9615 ##################

 unsigned char Re_buf[11],counter=0;
 char sign=0;
float TO=0,TA=0;
void serialEvent();

//########################################
void DrawTriangle() {
 int n, i, cx = tft.width() / 2 - 1, cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;



 tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
 n = min(cx, cy);

 for (i = 0; i < n; i += 15) {
 tft.drawTriangle(
 cx , cy - i, // peak
 cx - i, cy + i, // bottom left
 cx + i, cy + i, // bottom right
 tft.color565(0, 0, i));
 }
}
void drawHome()
{

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 319, 240, 8, WHITE);     //Page border

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, RED);
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);  //Game

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, RED);   //RGB led
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);

  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, RED);
  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, WHITE); //Oscilloscope

  tft.setCursor(60, 20);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setFont();
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.print("Select on Option");
  tft.setCursor(70, 50);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setTextColor(LIME);
  tft.print("GSH.ir");
  tft.setTextColor(BLACK);

  tft.setCursor(80, 95);
  tft.print("Heater Setting");

  tft.setCursor(80, 145);
  tft.print("Motor  Setting");

  tft.setCursor(70, 195);
  tft.print("     Start");

  //tft.drawCircle(30, 30, 20, RED);
  //tft.fillCircle(111, 111, 30, WHITE);
  //  delay(500);
  //tft.drawRoundRect(120, 192, 60, 64, 15, YELLOW);
  // tft.fillRoundRect(0, 192, 60, 64, 15, CYAN);

   // tft.drawRect(0, 0, 60, 64, CYAN);

   //  tft.fillRect(180, 192, 60, 64, GREY);
     //DrawTriangle();


} 

void drawstart(bool k)
{

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 319, 240, 8, WHITE);     //Page border

//  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, RED);
//  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);  //Game
//
//  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, RED);   //RGB led
//  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);
//
  tft.fillRoundRect(90, 60, 160, 60, 18, RED);
  tft.drawRoundRect(90, 60, 160, 60, 18, WHITE); //Oscilloscope

  tft.setCursor(40, 180);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.setFont();
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);

  if (k) {
    tft.print("Motor on time");
  }else{
    tft.print("Heater on time");
  }



} 
void drawMenu(bool k)
{
   tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  tft.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 319, 240, 8, WHITE);     //Page border

//  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, RED);
//  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 180, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);  //Game
//
//  tft.fillRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, RED);   //RGB led
//  tft.drawRoundRect(60, 130, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);
//
//  tft.fillRoundRect(75, 80, 160, 60, 18, BLUE);
 // tft.drawRoundRect(700, 60, 160, 80, 18, WHITE); //Oscilloscope

  //tft.fillTriangle(60,60,20,120,180,180,RED);
  tft.fillRoundRect(70, 75, 180, 70, 18, GREEN);
   //tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, RED);
   tft.fillTriangle(260,90, 260, 130, 300, 110, RED);
   tft.fillTriangle(60,90, 60, 130, 20, 110, RED);

  tft.setCursor(45, 180);
  tft.setTextSize(2.95);
  tft.setFont();
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  if (k) {
    tft.print("Motor Timer Setting");
  }else{
    tft.print("Heater Timer Setting");
  }
//  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 80, 60, 8, WHITE);
//  delay(70);

  tft.setTextSize(4);
  tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 80, 60, 8, RED);
  tft.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 80, 60, 8, WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(20,20);
  tft.print("<-");

   tft.fillRoundRect(230, 5, 85, 60, 8, BLUE);
  tft.drawRoundRect(230, 5, 85, 60, 8, WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(250, 20);
  tft.print("OK");


}

void start(){
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
   drawstart(0);
   setTime(0, 0, 1, 20, 1, 2013); // hour, min, sec, day, month, year
  lastHour = hour();

          //check for heater key pressed

   heater_key=1;state =1;
 while (state ){

   if ( lastSecond!=second())
   {
       lastMinute = minute();
       lastSecond=second();
       tft.setTextSize(6);
       tft.fillRoundRect(60, 60, 200, 100, 18, RED);
       //tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
       tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       tft.setCursor(110, 85);
       tft.print(lastMinute);
       tft.setCursor(140,85);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 85);
       tft.print(lastSecond);
       //delay(1000);
   }    
   if (heater_key)
    {
      // alarm set
      if ((Heater_alarmSecond_end <= lastSecond) && (Heater_alarmMinutes_end == lastMinute))
      {
         state=0;
         digitalWrite(A5, LOW);


      }
       if ((Heater_alarmSecond_end >= lastSecond) || (Heater_alarmMinutes_end >= lastMinute))
         {
          //sound alarm
          digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
          //setOffAlarm();
         }
     }
   }


    drawstart(1); 
    state =1;
   setTime(0, 0, 0, 20, 1, 2013); // hour, min, sec, day, month, year
   while (state){
   if ( lastSecond!=second())
   {
       lastMinute = minute();
       lastSecond=second();
       tft.setTextSize(6);
       tft.fillRoundRect(60, 60, 200, 100, 18, RED);
       //tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
       tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       tft.setCursor(110, 85);
       tft.print(lastMinute);
       tft.setCursor(140,85);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 85);
       tft.print(lastSecond);
       //delay(1000);
   }  
   if (1)
    {
      // alarm set
      if ((Motor_alarmSecond_end <= lastSecond) && (Motor_alarmMinutes_end == lastMinute))
      {
         state=0;
         digitalWrite(A6, LOW);


      }
       if ((Motor_alarmSecond_end >= lastSecond) || (Motor_alarmMinutes_end >= lastMinute))
         {
          //sound alarm
          digitalWrite(A6, HIGH);
          //setOffAlarm();
         }
     }
   }

//########### MLX90615 @#############
   char i=0,sum=0;

//  for (i=0;i<100;i++){
   score=1;
    while(score==1){
    serialEvent();
    if(sign)
    {
       sign=0;
       for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        sum+=Re_buf[i];
       if(sum==Re_buf[i] )
       {
             TO=(float)(Re_buf[4]<<8|Re_buf[5])/100;
             if ((int)TO>=30){
              score=0;
             }
             tft.setTextSize(3);
             Serial.print("TO:");
             Serial.println(TO);
            tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
            tft.setCursor(10, 15);
            tft.print("Temprature :");
            tft.setCursor(10, 50);
            tft.print(TO);tft.setCursor(100, 30);tft.print("C");
             TA=(float)(Re_buf[6]<<8|Re_buf[7])/100;
             Serial.print("TA:");
             Serial.println(TA);
             delay(100);
     }
    }
  }
//####################
   delay(1000);
   drawHome();
   return;

}

void menu(){

// drawMenu();

 TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();     // Read touchscreen
 state =1;
// while(state){
// if (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE)
if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000)
    {
     tft.setTextSize(3);
            tft.setTextColor(RED);
            tft.setCursor(10, 10);
            tft.print(p.x);
            delay(500);

  }
// }
}
//########## MLX90615    #############
void serialEvent(){ 
  while (Serial1.available()) {
    Re_buf[counter]=(unsigned char)Serial1.read();
    if(counter==0&&Re_buf[0]!=0x5A) return;
    counter++;
    if(counter==9)
    {
       counter=0;
       sign=1;
    }
  }
}
//########################

void setup()
{

  time_t t = now(); // store the current time in time variable t
  pinMode(A5, OUTPUT);pinMode(A6, OUTPUT); 

  tft.reset();
  tft.begin(tft.readID());
//  Serial.begin(9600);
//  Serial.println();
//  Serial.print("reading id...");
//  delay(500);
//  Serial.println(tft.readID(), HEX);


  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.setRotation(1);

  currentpage = 0;

  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(50, 140);
  tft.print("Loading...");

  tft.setTextColor(tft.color565(255, 255, 0));
  tft.setCursor(30, 70);
  tft.print("By:");

  tft.setCursor(30, 100);
  tft.print("NotesPoint.com GSH.IR");

  for (int i; i < 250; i++)
  {
    tft.fillRect(BAR_MINY - 10, BLUEBAR_MINX, i, 10, RED);
    delay(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  score=14;
  if (EEPROM.read(1)==score){
  address=2;
  tft.setCursor(300, 100);
  tft.print("eeprom writed beffor");
  Heater_alarmSecond_end = EEPROM.read(address);
  Heater_alarmMinutes_end= EEPROM.read(address+1);
  Motor_alarmSecond_end = EEPROM.read(address+2);
  Motor_alarmMinutes_end = EEPROM.read(address+3);
  }
  else{
    tft.setCursor(300, 100);
  tft.print("new eeprom");
    address=1;
  EEPROM.write(address,14);
  EEPROM.write(address+1,10);
  EEPROM.write(address+2,4);
  EEPROM.write(address+3,10);
  EEPROM.write(address+4,0);
  address=1;

  Heater_alarmSecond_end = EEPROM.read(address);
  Heater_alarmMinutes_end= EEPROM.read(address+1);
  Motor_alarmSecond_end = EEPROM.read(address+2);
  Motor_alarmMinutes_end = EEPROM.read(address+3);
  }
  delay(1000);
  drawHome();
  setTime(0, 0, 0, 20, 1, 2013); // hour, min, sec, day, month, year
  //########### MLX90615 ############

Serial1.begin(115200);Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1);
  Serial1.write(0XA5);
  Serial1.write(0X45);
  Serial1.write(0XEA);
  Serial.write(0XA5);

//#############################

}
void loop()
{

//  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();     // Read touchscreen
//  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);
//########### MLX90615 @#############
   char i=0,sum=0;

//  for (i=0;i<100;i++){
   score=1;
    while(score==1){
    serialEvent();
    if(sign)
    {
       sign=0;
       for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        sum+=Re_buf[i];
       if(sum==Re_buf[i] )
       {
             TO=(float)(Re_buf[4]<<8|Re_buf[5])/100;
             if ((int)TO>=30){
              score=0;
             }
             tft.setTextSize(3);
             Serial.print("TO:");
             Serial.println(TO);
            tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
            tft.setCursor(10, 15);
            tft.print("Temprature :");
            tft.setCursor(10, 50);
            tft.print(TO);tft.setCursor(100, 30);tft.print("C");
             TA=(float)(Re_buf[6]<<8|Re_buf[7])/100;
             Serial.print("TA:");
             Serial.println(TA);
             delay(100);
     }
    }
  }
//####################
  if (currentpage == 0)
  {
    if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000)
    {


      if (p.x > 736 && p.x < 855 && p.y > 255 && p.y < 725  && p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE)
      {

        start();

//        delay(1000);

      }

      else if (p.x > 563 && p.x < 683 && p.y > 275 && p.y < 750)
      {


        currentpage = 4;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        p.z = 0;
/
      drawMenu(1);
      tft.setTextSize(6);
       tft.fillRoundRect(70, 75, 180, 70, 18, GREEN);
            tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       if (Motor_alarmMinutes_end==10){
       tft.setCursor(85, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(145,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmSecond_end);
       }else{
       tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       tft.setCursor(110, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(140,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmSecond_end);

       }


      }


      if (p.x > 403 && p.x < 525 && p.y > 271 && p.y < 725)
      {
//        Serial.println("Oscilloscope");

        currentpage =5;

//        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);
//        delay(70);
//
//        tft.fillRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, RED);
//        tft.drawRoundRect(60, 80, 200, 40, 8, WHITE);
//
//        tft.setCursor(80, 95);
//        tft.print("Oscilloscope");
//        delay(70);
        drawMenu(0);
        tft.setTextSize(6);
       tft.fillRoundRect(70, 75, 180, 70, 18, GREEN);
            tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       if (Heater_alarmMinutes_end==10){
       tft.setCursor(85, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(145,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmSecond_end);
       }else{
       tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       tft.setCursor(110, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(140,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmSecond_end);

       }
//        drawOSC();

      }
    }

  }

  if (currentpage == 4){
//   menu();


       //tft.fillScreen(BLACK);


if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000)
    {
//     tft.setTextSize(3);
//            tft.setTextColor(RED);
//            tft.setCursor(10, 10);
//            tft.print(p.x);
//            //delay(500);

       tft.setTextSize(6);
       tft.fillRoundRect(70, 75, 180, 70, 18, GREEN);
            tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       if (Motor_alarmMinutes_end>=10){
       tft.setCursor(85, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(145,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmSecond_end);
       }else{
       tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       tft.setCursor(110, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(140,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Motor_alarmSecond_end);

       }

      if (p.y > 600 && p.x < 650 && p.x > 400 && p.y < 885)
        {
         if (Motor_alarmSecond_end==0){
                Motor_alarmSecond_end=59;
                if (Motor_alarmMinutes_end==0){
                    Motor_alarmMinutes_end=10;}
                else {
                      Motor_alarmMinutes_end=Motor_alarmMinutes_end-1;
                }
                }
          else {
            Motor_alarmSecond_end=Motor_alarmSecond_end-1;
            }
           }


          if (p.y > 150 && p.x < 700 && p.x > 400 && p.y < 400)
        {
         if (Motor_alarmSecond_end==59){
                Motor_alarmSecond_end=0;
                if (Motor_alarmMinutes_end==10){
                    Motor_alarmMinutes_end=0;
                     }
                else {
                      Motor_alarmMinutes_end=Motor_alarmMinutes_end+1;
                     }
                }
          else {
            Motor_alarmSecond_end=Motor_alarmSecond_end+1;
            }
           }
       if (p.y > 200 && p.x < 375 && p.x > 200 && p.y < 350)
      {

          EEPROM.write(address+3,Motor_alarmSecond_end);
          EEPROM.write(address+4,Motor_alarmMinutes_end);

        currentpage = 0;
        drawHome();
//        p.x = 160;
//        p.y = 760;
        return;
      }
       if (p.y > 750 && p.x < 315 && p.x > 50 && p.y < 1000)
      {

        currentpage = 0;
        drawHome();

        return;
      }


  }
}


if (currentpage == 5){
//   menu();


       //tft.fillScreen(BLACK);


if (p.z > 10 && p.z < 1000)
    {
//     tft.setTextSize(3);
//            tft.setTextColor(RED);
//            tft.setCursor(10, 10);
//            tft.print(p.x);
//            //delay(500);

       tft.setTextSize(6);
       tft.fillRoundRect(70, 75, 180, 70, 18, GREEN);
            tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       if (Heater_alarmMinutes_end>=10){
       tft.setCursor(85, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(145,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmSecond_end);
       }else{
       tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
       tft.setCursor(110, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmMinutes_end);
       tft.setCursor(140,90);
       tft.print(":");
       tft.setCursor(170, 90);
       tft.print(Heater_alarmSecond_end);

       }

        if (p.y > 600 && p.x < 650 && p.x > 400 && p.y < 885)
        {
         if (Heater_alarmSecond_end==0){
                Heater_alarmSecond_end=59;
                if (Heater_alarmMinutes_end==0){
                    Heater_alarmMinutes_end=10;}
                else {
                      Heater_alarmMinutes_end=Heater_alarmMinutes_end-1;
                }
                }
          else {
            Heater_alarmSecond_end=Heater_alarmSecond_end-1;
            }
           }


          if (p.y > 150 && p.x < 700 && p.x > 400 && p.y < 400)
        {
         if (Heater_alarmSecond_end==59){
                Heater_alarmSecond_end=0;
                if (Heater_alarmMinutes_end==10){
                    Heater_alarmMinutes_end=0;
                }
                else {
                      Heater_alarmMinutes_end=Heater_alarmMinutes_end+1;
                }
                }
          else {
            Heater_alarmSecond_end=Heater_alarmSecond_end+1;
            }
           }
        if (p.y > 200 && p.x < 375 && p.x > 200 && p.y < 350)
      {


          address=1;
          EEPROM.write(address+1,Heater_alarmSecond_end);
          EEPROM.write(address+2,Heater_alarmMinutes_end);

        currentpage = 0;
        drawHome();
//        p.x = 160;
//        p.y = 760;
        return;
      }
      if (p.y > 750 && p.x < 315 && p.x > 50 && p.y < 1000)
      {

        currentpage = 0;
        drawHome();
//        p.x = 160;
//        p.y = 760;
        return;
      }


  }
}
  if (currentpage == 1) //Flappy bird
  {
    senseBack();
    if (millis() > nextDrawLoopRunTime && !crashed) {
      drawLoop();
      checkCollision();
      nextDrawLoopRunTime += DRAW_LOOP_INTERVAL;
    }
    if (backsensed)
    {
      currentpage = 0;
      drawHome();
    }


    sensereset();

    ResetScore();

    // Process user input   If sensed a touch anywere on the screen eccept the area of the reset button
    if (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE && !scrPress && !resetsensed && !backsensed) {     //p.x < 199 && p.y < 293
      if (crashed) {
        // restart game
        startGame();
      }
      else if (!running) {
        // clear and restart
        tft.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 80, BLUE);
        running = true;
      }
      else
      {
        // Go up
        fallRate = -8;
        scrPress = true;
      }
    }
    else if (p.z == 0 && scrPress) {
      scrPress = false;
    }
  }

  if (currentpage == 2) // RGB mixer
  {

    if (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE)
    {
      x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, tft.width(), 0);
      y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY,  tft.height(), 0) + 30;

      tft.fillRoundRect(200, 5, 70, 40, 8, tft.color565(redval, greenval, blueval));

      if (y > 42 && y < 250)
      {
        if (x > 180 && x < 220)
        {

          redval = map(y, 42, 250, 0, 255);
          oldrpos = redpos;
          tft.fillRect(oldrpos, REDBAR_MINX + 3, BAR_WIDTH - 10, BAR_WIDTH - 5, BLACK);
          redpos = y;
          tft.fillRect(redpos, REDBAR_MINX + 3, BAR_WIDTH - 10, BAR_WIDTH - 5, RED);      //tft.drawRect(BAR_MINY, REDBAR_MINX, BAR_HEIGHT, BAR_WIDTH, WHITE);
          tft.fillCircle(14, REDBAR_MINX + 15, 10, tft.color565(redval, 0, 0));


        }

        if (x > 115 && x < 150)
        {
          greenval = map(y, 42, 250, 0, 255);
          oldgpos = greenpos;
          tft.fillRect(oldgpos, GREENBAR_MINX + 3, BAR_WIDTH - 10, BAR_WIDTH - 5, BLACK);
          greenpos = y;
          tft.fillRect(greenpos, GREENBAR_MINX + 3, BAR_WIDTH - 10, BAR_WIDTH - 5, GREEN);      //tft.drawRect(BAR_MINY, REDBAR_MINX, BAR_HEIGHT, BAR_WIDTH, WHITE);
          tft.fillCircle(14, GREENBAR_MINX + 15, 10, tft.color565(0, greenval, 0));


        }
        if (x > 40 && x < 80)
        {
          blueval = map(y, 42, 250, 0, 255);
          oldbpos = bluepos;
          tft.fillRect(oldbpos, BLUEBAR_MINX + 3, BAR_WIDTH - 10, BAR_WIDTH - 5, BLACK);
          bluepos = y;
          tft.fillRect(bluepos, BLUEBAR_MINX + 3, BAR_WIDTH - 10, BAR_WIDTH - 5, BLUE);      //tft.drawRect(BAR_MINY, REDBAR_MINX, BAR_HEIGHT, BAR_WIDTH, WHITE);
          tft.fillCircle(14, BLUEBAR_MINX + 15, 10, tft.color565(0, 0, blueval));


        }
      }

      if (p.y > 743 && p.x < 247 && p.x > 150 && p.y < 875)
      {
        tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, WHITE);
        delay(70);
        tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, BLUE);
        tft.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, WHITE);
        tft.setCursor(15, 15);
        tft.print("<-");
        delay(70);
        tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, BLACK);
        currentpage = 0;
        drawHome();
        p.x = 160;
        p.y = 760;
        redval = 0;
        blueval = 0;
        greenval = 0;
        redpos = BAR_MINY + 12;
        greenpos = BAR_MINY + 12;
        bluepos = BAR_MINY + 12;
        oldrpos = redpos;
        oldgpos = greenpos;
        oldbpos = bluepos;

      }
    }

  }

  if (currentpage == 3)  //Oscilloscope
  {
    for (uint16_t j = 0; j <= tft.width() + 1; j++ )

    {
      float volt;
      float signalY = map(analogRead(A5),  0,  4095,  tft.height() - 1,  1   ) ;


      tft.drawFastVLine( j,  46, tft.height(), BLACK);
      tft.drawFastHLine(j, 180.00, 1, RED);
      tft.drawFastHLine(j, 195.00, 1, WHITE);

      tft.drawPixel(j, signalY, GOLD);


      if (p.z > MINPRESSURE && p.z < MAXPRESSURE)
        if (p.y > 743 && p.x < 247 && p.x > 150 && p.y < 875)
        {
          tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, WHITE);
          delay(70);
          tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, BLUE);
          tft.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, WHITE);
          tft.setCursor(15, 15);
          tft.print("<-");
          delay(70);
          tft.fillRoundRect(5, 5, 50, 30, 8, BLACK);
          currentpage = 0;
          drawHome();
          p.x = 160;
          p.y = 760;
          return;
        }

    }
  }

}

void drawLoop() { //Flappy bird functions
  // clear moving items
  clearPillar(pillarPos, gapPosition);   //Clear pillar
  clearFlappy(flX, flY);            //Clear bird

  // Move items
  if (running) {
    flY += fallRate;
    fallRate++;

    pillarPos -= 5;
    if (pillarPos == 0) {
      score++;
    }
    else if (pillarPos < -50) {
      pillarPos = 320;
      gapPosition = random(20, 120);    //Random gap position
    }
  }
```

So now i removed this part from my program but how could I add this font to my library?

Update:

My arduino Version is 1.8.9 similar this:

[image]
Thanks

Comment: How did you install the Linux version of Arduino? Did you download from arduino.cc? If not you are probably using a very very very old version that does not include the library include mechanism.

Comment: really i don't remember how to installed it but  in arduino website the version 1.8.9 which is mine is the last version.